# Why does my Ubuntu 20.04's top bar's icon becomes small every time when I boot the PC?

Tags: 20.04, icons, top-bar

I am facing this issue with Ubuntu's top bar that every time when I restart or boot up my PC the icons from top bar will become smaller and then I need to got to Universal Access and turn the large text on. I have tried every possible internet things but nothing works and I filed to find the problem.

[Here is the image of smaller icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB2kk.jpg)

Can anyone suggest better solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in mutter that might be your problem.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892521

I seen two work arounds in these threads that you can try. Or wait for bug fix.

Downgrade libmutter:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440/comments/17

Create script and run each starup:
For this one, please notice you rather like scale up and not down.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892521/comments/27